# Why empty plot (Dsolve solution)?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

When I try to plot the `DSolve` output, I get empty plot.

Here is the code

```
Eq1 = -(r + k)/k*(1 + 1/beta)*D[(D[u[r], r] - (u[r] + 1)/(r + k)), r] == p
bcs1 =  u[-1] == 1;
bcs2 = u[1] == 1;
sol = DSolve[{Eq1, bcs1, bcs2}, u[r], r]
k = 0.1; beta = 0.1; p = 0.1;
Plot[u[r] /. sol, {r, -1, 1}]
```

I have no idea where, I made a mistake.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: When something won't plot, it's useful to look at the numerical values. ThingThatWontPlot/.variable->SomeSensibleValue//N

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to see the problem, is to evaluate the solution, using `Table` for some values:

```
 Chop@Table[u[r] /. sol, {r, -1, 1, .1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the solution is complex valued.  So to plot it, use `Re` and `Im`

```
 Plot[Re[u[r] /. sol], {r, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[Im[u[r] /. sol], {r, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]